# mat data type = 17 is not supported

Tags: python, opencv

I am simply trying to convert an image from BGR to RGB using opencv in python.
But when doing so I get this error message:

```
line 62, in getRep\n    rgbImg = cv2.cvtColor(imgFrame, 

cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)\nTypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported\n
```

I watched the image being passed as an argument and it is in BGR as I expected, yet it doesn't work:

```
def getRep(self, imgFrame, multiple=False):
    bgrImg = imgFrame.copy()
    cv2.imshow('debug', imgFrame)   #this line does show a BGR image
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    rgbImg = cv2.cvtColor(imgFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


def recognize(self, imgFramePath):
    imgFrame= cv2.imread(imgFramePath)
    imgFrame = np.array(imgFrame)
    reps = self.getRep(imgFrame, False)
```

Those are all the lines being interpreted and the only ones that are related to the issue I am facing. Does anybody know what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. Can you please add the output of imgFrame.dtype?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is a `CV_8S` image (8-bit signed integer). [This site](http://ninghang.blogspot.com/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html) shows conversion from the numeric data types to the actual types, and type 17 corresponds to 8-bit signed int. This is the problem as `cvtColor()` does not accept 8-bit signed int images for the input. From the docs on [`cvtColor()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor):

> **src** – input image: 8-bit unsigned, 16-bit unsigned (`CV_16UC...`), or single-precision floating-point.

So your input image needs to be of type `CV_8U` (`numpy.uint8`) or `CV_16U` (`numpy.uint16`) or `CV_32F` (`numpy.float32`) with the proper number of channels for the color conversion you're using.